# PL/SQL Output column results in dbms_output.put_line LOOP

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle12c

Good morning,
I will start out saying that I have already done 97% of this as yes, it is homework.  The ONLY part I am confused with is not understanding the Error that is given.  I had to create a loop that would take 2 numbers given and then output which numbers both are commonly divisible by.  Here is that code:

```
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE UNLIMITED

--DROP TABLE IF IT EXISTS
DROP TABLE TESTER1 cascade constraints;
--CREATE TESTER1 TABLE
CREATE TABLE TESTER1 (xnum number, num1 number, num2 number);
--DECLARE VARIABLES
DECLARE 
   Test_Number1 number := 10;
   Test_Number2 number := 20;
   x number := 1;
--BEGIN   
BEGIN --OUTSIDE LOOP
    LOOP
        BEGIN --INSIDE LOOP
            INSERT INTO TESTER1(xnum,num1,num2)
            VALUES(x,MOD(Test_Number1,x),MOD(Test_Number2,x));
            x := x + 1;
        EXIT WHEN NOT x < 20;
        EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('error');
        END;
    END LOOP; --INSIDE LOOP
END; --OUTSIDE LOOP
/
```

I then wrote a SELECT statement to find where both have a common divisor:

```
SELECT xnum FROM tester1
where num1=num2;
```

My Question is:  How do I loop through the results from the table Tester1 and use dbms_output.put_line() so each result from the SELECT statement is inserted until it loops through 3 rows?
I hope I explained it well enough.  I am using Oracle 12c.

Comment: That may be the part I am missing.  I have looked through tons of posts on here of people asking a similar loop or output question, but all dealing with mssql.  I believe a few of them had a Curser in there and so maybe that Is what I should look into if you believe that would help. @Abra

Comment: Yes, I also have the Oracle Database 12c PL/SQL Programming book by Michael McLaughlin (Oracle ACE) open next to me and reviewing the Curser For Loop page on oracletutorial.  I found something I am wanting to try, just refreshed this page before I started.

Comment: I think [this section](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/static.htm#LNPLS553) in PL/SQL Language Reference can help you. There are a lot of examples in the documentation, so it's better to check them to be familiar with the DBMS abilities before deep dive into details with special books.

Comment: Awesome thank you!  I will update this with the solution I just found once I get it formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the answer I have found and just need to try and incorporate into my previous statement is:

```
BEGIN
    FOR r_xnum IN (SELECT xnum FROM tester1
where num1=num2)
    LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('Common factor: ' ||r_xnum.xnum);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Thanks again for all that pointed me in the right direction.  It has been awhile since I posted here last so not sure how to close out the question without completely deleting it, so I will keep it how it is unless someone else knows how. *EDIT* I have to wait 2 days until I can accept my own answer

Final run:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE UNLIMITED

--DROP TABLE IF IT EXISTS
DROP TABLE TESTER1 cascade constraints;
--CREATE TESTER1 TABLE
CREATE TABLE TESTER1 (xnum number, num1 number, num2 number);

--DECLARE VARIABLES
DECLARE 
   Test_Number1 number := '&input1';
   Test_Number2 number := '&input2';
   x number := 1;
--BEGIN   
BEGIN --LOOP 1
    LOOP --LOOP FOR INSERT
        BEGIN --INSIDE LOOP
            INSERT INTO TESTER1(xnum,num1,num2)
            VALUES(x,MOD(Test_Number1,x),MOD(Test_Number2,x));
            x := x + 1;
            EXIT WHEN NOT x < 20;
       END;
    END LOOP; --LOOP 1
        BEGIN --LOOP FOR SELECT
            dbms_output.put_line('The two numbers enetered are ' ||Test_Number1|| 'and '||Test_Number2);
            FOR r_xnum IN (SELECT xnum FROM tester1
                where num1=num2)
            LOOP
                dbms_output.put_line('Common factor: ' ||r_xnum.xnum);
            END LOOP;
        END;
END;
/
```

Comment: Don't delete it, just accept your own answer.